# Vector3f or Vector3d?

Tags: java, vector, simulation, physics

I have a system currently using Vector3d for a particle physics simulator, but I have been considering Vector3f.  Which is more commonly used?  What are the pros/cons of each?  Also, where can I download Vector3d?

Comment: One is float another is double prolly. Use the one that makes sense I guess. Context?

Comment: That is the case.  I was wondering about performance issues and popularity.  The application is a particle physics simulator.

Comment: Data types in physics simulations are selected based on deep understanding of the phenomena, the stability of the simulation, and the trade-off between precision and computational speed, not on popularity.

Comment: Opinion based?  ROFL!  Trolls!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Vector3f` uses `float` values to store the numbers, and `Vector3d` uses `double`s. If you need very high accuracy, use `Vector3d`. In most cases you don't need that high accuracy, so use `Vector3f` to save storage space.

Comment: Good answer.  Might mention doubles can store a greater range of numbers than floats, even though its implied by storage space.

Answer (score 1):

For a particle physics simulator I'd strongly consider using [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) to avoid floating-point rounding errors using doubles and floats (which Vector3f and Vector3d use, respectively) messing up your calculations.

Of course, if the simulation needs to be real-time then you'll have to think of the time and space complexity implications of using BigDecimal vs double vs float but if it's to be run offline, BigDecimal's exact representation of fractional numbers is a big win for this type of application.